# android - SDK 4.0 on android 2.1

Tags: android

Even though I have done some app on android, I am still confused. Is it possible to use functions in SDK 4.0, and run the app on android 2.1 or lower?

I tried methods you guys mentioned but got an error -

Field requires API level 11 (current min is 7): android.os.AsyncTask#THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, if I change min to 11, the app can't install on android 2.1, so even I can use higher API, but it still can't run on android lower version...how to fix that?

From Kzinch's advice, set TargetApi to 11, then it's working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use functions from the higher API in your code, but you must make sure they are never called on the lower API in runtime.

You should make checks for API level in runtime and provide alternative implementation that exists for that API level.

Let me provide some simple example:

```
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity()).edit();
    edit.putInt(KEY, VALUE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 9) {
        edit.apply();
    } else {
        edit.commit();
    }
```

`apply()` method is a faster (asynchronous) implementation of `commit()` method, but it not supported on the API level less than 9. With the help of API version check it all works perfect for all devices.

**Update** @TargetApi annotaion may be used to suppress Lint warnings/errors for API checks.

Comment: Thanks. Did u mean I can use SDK 4.0, with compare with its SDK number, so I can choose which function is suit to be used in current system?

Comment: I tried your method, got an error. - Field requires API level 11 (current min is 7): android.os.AsyncTask#THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, if I change min to 11, the app can't install on android 2.1, how to fix that?

Comment: You should set API level 11 in your project settings. Minimum API level in the manifest may still be 7. Also, use `@TargetApi` annotation to suppress Lint errors. By doing this you tell Lint that you know what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks Kzinch, you are the best when I set TargetApi to 11, it's working!

Answer (score 2):

If you want a program that runs on both SDK4 and SDK 2.1 you have two possibilities. One is to provide alternative implementations on your code when they are needed i.e., if some function from SDK4 is not available in the SDK2.1 then you add a conditional block to your code that check the SDK version and provide code for each branch.

The other possibility is to use the [Android Support Libaries](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) in order to use **the same code** for both SDKs (no conditional blocks required). If you need a function provided by the SDK4 but not for the SDK2.1 you can check if that function is provided by a support library. If it is you can use it and your code will run fine on both SDK4 and SDK2.1 without requiring any version checking. For instance, if you need to use the `LruCache` class which is available since API level 12 (and so not available on SDK2.1) you can use the v4 support library which provide that function and works on SDK2.1 and SDK4. So in your code you would use

```
import android.support.v4.util.LruCache;
```

instead of

```
import android.util.LruCache;
```

Comment: actually I use SDK4, and want the app running on android 2.1 fine, now seems not work.

Comment: I understand what you want. I've edited my answer trying to explain better what I mean. Hope my answer helps now.

Comment: Your answer is valid one too, just not relevant to what I need anyway thanks!

Answer (score 1):

it doesn't matter what SDK level you compile your code against. Important is which methods/classes are you calling/instantiating.

If you use any newer classes or methods your code WILL crash running on older devices.
The suggested method to deal with it is Lazy Loading: http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2010/07/how-to-have-your-cupcake-and-eat-it-too.html

and remember, I'm saying this about the SDK.

The compatibility pack is a library developed by google that you can add to any project and use the functions of the library without issues.

Furthermore, there're 3rd party libraries (such as the ActionBar Sherlock http://actionbarsherlock.com/ that aims to bring higher SDK level functionalities to lower SDK levels)

Answer (score 1):

No. You cannot **use** methods from higher API, because the code to handle it is simply not present on lower version of API. You can, however target as high API version as possible, but you may take care to call these methods on right API. You can easily check that at runtime with. i.e.

```
f( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ) {
     // code to be run on Honeycomb and higher versions
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the API which are specific to higher version, then the app wont work in older version.As those are not defined in the older version it will throw an error.That is the reason we restrict apps before uploading into market using minSDK in AndroidManifest.xml.